# ¿Cómo Incluir audio a etiqueta estilizada de html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Estoy trabajando con un reproductor de musica que sólo funciona gráficamente pero necesito incluirle una canción que se reproduzca automáticamente al cargar mi html.

El siguiente código gráficamente es:

```
     <a class="music-bg">
        <div class="lines">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
            <p> Musica </p>
      </a>
```

Y el CSS para darle efectos de barras de sonido ecualizador es el sig:

```
   /* Musica Bg */
   .music-bg {
   display: block;
   cursor: pointer;
   padding: 40px 0;
   text-align: center;
   border-top: 5px solid #fff;
   visibility: hidden;
   z-index: 10;
   -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
   -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
   -o-transition: all .3s ease;
   transition: all 0.3s ease;
 }

  .music-bg p {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
 }

.music-bg .lines {
 display: flex;
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
 margin: 0 auto 10px;
 align-items: flex-end;
}

 .music-bg .lines span {
 display: inline-flex;
 margin: 0px 1px;
 width: 7px;
 height: 5px;
 background: #fff;
 }

 .audio-on .music-bg .lines span:nth-child(1) {
 -webkit-animation: musicline 2s 0.5s ease-out alternate infinite;
 animation: musicline 2s 0.5s ease-out alternate infinite;
 }  

.audio-on .music-bg .lines span:nth-child(2) {
-webkit-animation: musicline 2s 1s ease-out alternate infinite;
 animation: musicline 2s 1s ease-out alternate infinite;
 } 

 .audio-on .music-bg .lines span:nth-child(3) {
 -webkit-animation: musicline 2s 1.5s ease-out alternate infinite;
 animation: musicline 2s 1.5s ease-out alternate infinite;
 }

 .audio-on .music-bg .lines span:nth-child(4) {
 -webkit-animation: musicline 2s 0.25s ease-out alternate infinite;
 animation: musicline 2s 0.25s ease-out alternate infinite;
 }

 .audio-on .music-bg .lines span:nth-child(5) {
 -webkit-animation: musicline 2s 0.75s ease-out alternate infinite;
 animation: musicline 2s 0.75s ease-out alternate infinite;
 }

 .audio-on .music-bg .lines span:nth-child(6) {
 -webkit-animation: musicline 2s 1.25s ease-out alternate infinite;
 animation: musicline 2s 1.25s ease-out alternate infinite;
 }

  @keyframes musicline {
0% {height: 5px;}
10% {height: 10px;}
20% {height: 5px;}
30% {height: 14px;}
40% {height: 18px;}
50% {height: 5px;}
60% {height: 16px;}
70% {height: 10px;}
80% {height: 12px;}
90% {height: 4px;}
100% {height: 18px;}
```

}

El código CSS sólo da el aspecto de reproducir una canción **(PERO NO HAY DICHA CANCIÓN)** y el usuario puede dar clic para pausar dicho efecto, como se muestra en las imágenes.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

NECESITO REALMENTE INCLUIR UNA CANCIÓN CON ESTE CÓDIGO YA CREÁDO. 
AGRADEZCO SUS CONSEJOS

Comment: Echa un ojo a la etiqueta audio https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me gustaría compartir lo que fue útil para mi en "La Web del Programador" donde me pudieron ayudar:

**Primero**
Defino mi etiqueta `<a class="music-bg">` que ya fue estilizada con CSS.

**Despues**
Asingno un evento Onclick de JS llamado control y también utilizaré la etiqueta `<audio>` para enlazar mi canción dandole autoplay loop como propiedades:

```
            <a class="music-bg" onclick="control()">
                <div class="lines">
                    <!--Link de Canción-->
                    <audio src="extras/canción.mp3" autoplay loop></audio>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                </div>
                <p> Musica </p>
            </a>
```

**Por ultimo**
Defino entre etiquetas de JS las funciones del evento llamando por su ID  a mi etiqueta estilizada, por lo cual tendré que escribir una variable contador para que se pueda reproducir el audio a partir de que se carga y se presiona "n" cantidad de veces:

```
 <script>
        var contador=1;
        var audio=document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
        audio.play();

        function control(){

            contador = contador+1
            if (contador%2==0){
                audio.pause();
            } else {
                audio.play();
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Tu css esta incompleto, faltaba el @keyframes en tu css, ademas si deseas controlar música en html necesitas utilizar la etiqueta `<audio>` https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp  aquí puedes aprender como se utiliza.

```
 @keyframes musicline {
  from {height: 3px;}
  to {height: 9px;}
}
```

Con el script jquery que he realizado podrás parar o activas la animación de reproducción.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var isplay = false;
 var audio = document.getElementById("musica");
    
      $(".music-bg").click(function () { 
        if(isplay){
              $(".music-bg").removeClass( "audio-on");
        audio.pause();
              isplay = false;
        }else{
              $(".music-bg").addClass( "audio-on");
        audio.play();
              isplay = true;
        }
      });
        
    });
```

```css
     .music-bg {
       background:#000;
       display: block;
       cursor: pointer;
       padding: 40px 0;
       text-align: center;
       border-top: 5px solid #fff;
       z-index: 10;
       -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
       -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
       -o-transition: all .3s ease;
       transition: all 0.3s ease;
     }

      .music-bg p {
      color: #fff;
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight: 600;
      
     }

    .music-bg .lines {
     display: flex;
     width: 24px;
     height: 24px;
     margin: 0 auto 10px;
     align-items: flex-end;
    }

     .music-bg .lines span {
     display: inline-flex;
     margin: 0px 1px;
     width: 7px;
     height: 5px;
     background: #fff;
     }

     .audio-on .lines span:nth-child(1) {
     -webkit-animation: musicline 2s 0.5s ease-out alternate infinite;
     animation: musicline 2s 0.5s ease-out alternate infinite;
     }  

    .audio-on .lines span:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation: musicline 2s 1s ease-out alternate infinite;
     animation: musicline 2s 1s ease-out alternate infinite;
     } 

     .audio-on .lines span:nth-child(3) {
     -webkit-animation: musicline 2s 1.5s ease-out alternate infinite;
     animation: musicline 2s 1.5s ease-out alternate infinite;
     }

     .audio-on .lines span:nth-child(4) {
     -webkit-animation: musicline 2s 0.25s ease-out alternate infinite;
     animation: musicline 2s 0.25s ease-out alternate infinite;
     }

     .audio-on .lines span:nth-child(5) {
     -webkit-animation: musicline 2s 0.75s ease-out alternate infinite;
     animation: musicline 2s 0.75s ease-out alternate infinite;
     }

     .audio-on .lines span:nth-child(6) {
     -webkit-animation: musicline 2s 1.25s ease-out alternate infinite;
     animation: musicline 2s 1.25s ease-out alternate infinite;
     }
     
     @keyframes musicline {
      from {height: 3px;}
      to {height: 15px;}
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="music-bg">
        <div class="lines" >
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
            <p> Musica </p>
</div>
 
<audio id="musica" src="musica.m4a" loop></audio>
```

Vale esta es la manera de manejar un `<audio>` sin usar el atributo `controls`, para ello utilizo los métodos `play()` y `pause()` de javascript.

la lógica del script es bastante simple. si por algún casual usas el atributo `autoplay` la declaración de la variable `isplay` debe empezar en `true`

Comment: Hola @Andres Dominguez Bravo , agradezco tu tiempo en tu respuesta PERO no se si me explique bien y creo que sí. La animación ya la tengo y me funciona a la perfección, las barritas del efecto suben y bajan y si doy click sobre de ellas se detienen, pero lo que quiero ES AÑADIRLE UNA CANCIÓN A ESTE EFECTO cuando recién se carga el index y que al pausar el efecto de las barras, se pause también la canción. SALUDOS

Comment: La etiqueta audio la uso y si funciona con una canción de fondo en mi index, pero lo que necesito es relacionar esta etiqueta con mi animación en css.